# Frullani integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{csch}(x)-\frac1x}{x} {\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, improper-integrals

> $$
> \int_0^\infty \frac{\text{csch}(x)-\frac1x}{x} {\rm d}x.
> $$

This integral was from a recent contest like two weeks ago and I still can't crack it. Well, to be exact it was in the form of

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{2}{x^2} \left( \frac{x}{e^x - e^{-x}} - \frac12 \right) {\rm d}x.
$$

The hint was to turn it into *Frullani integral*, but nothing i've tried worked out, by-parts leaves you with something that doesn't converge and I can't find a way to turn the numerator into $f(ax)-f(bx)$. I noted that it can also be written in the form

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{csch}(\frac1x) - x}{x} {\rm d}x.$$

Comment: It's a local contest https://www.facebook.com/utarNMC/

Comment: Do you interest alternative way?

Comment: yeah of course, anything that works

Comment: The result below lead  to think that $a=2,b=1$

Comment: Can't we contour it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define the function $F$ for $x>0$ by:
\begin{align}F(x)=\text{cotanh}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\frac{2}{x}\end{align}
Observe that,
\begin{align}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  F(x)&=0\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}  F(x)&=1\\
F(x)-F(2x)&=\frac{1}{\sinh x}-\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}
On can use Frullani's theorem:
\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{csch}(x)-\frac1x}{x} {\rm d}x&=\int_0^\infty \frac{F(x)-F(2x)}{x}\,dx\\
&=\left(F(0)-F(\infty)\right)\ln\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)\\
&=\boxed{-\ln 2}
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) The only answer of the posted that actually uses Frullani.  You might be interested in [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746297/an-extended-frullani-integral), which extends the commonly seen version of Frullani,  and [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180443/integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-sqrtqx-sin-sqrtpxxdx/3667127#3667127), which converts the original integral to a Frullani integral.

Answer (score 8):

One way is using the expansion of $\operatorname{csch}x$, that is
$$\operatorname{csch}x=\dfrac{1}{x}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2(-1)^nx}{n^2\pi^2+x^2}$$
then
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\operatorname{csch}x-\frac1x}{x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}2(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{n^2\pi^2+x^2}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2(-1)^n}{n\pi}\arctan\dfrac{x}{n\pi}\Big|_{0}^{\infty}=\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}}=\color{blue}{\ln\dfrac12}$$

Comment: This doesn't use a Frullani integral, which was the thrust of the question.