# Evaluating integral $\int_0^{\infty } \left(\coth x-\frac{1}{x}\right) \text{csch} \>x\, dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am having trouble evaluating the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \left(\coth (x)-\frac{1}{x}\right) \text{csch}(x) \, dx\tag{1}$$

Numerically the integral appears to evaluate to $\log 2$.

The Weierstrass substitution doesn't help me other than allow a series approximation to be calculated using Mathematica. The Weierstrass substitution results in

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{t \tanh ^{-1}(t)}+1\right) \, dt\tag{2}$$

Any ideas?

Incidentally there seem to be a sequence of such integrals with closed forms:

$$I_n=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\coth^n (x)-\frac{1}{x^n}\right) x^{n-1}\text{csch}(x) \, dx\tag{3}$$

Comment: Alternate form $$\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {x\cosh \left( x \right)-\sinh \left( x
 \right) }{ x\left( \sinh \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}\,{\rm d}x$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as
$$I=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\coth x-\frac{1}{x}\right) \text{csch}x\, dx
= \int_0^{\infty } \frac{f(x)-f(\frac x2)}x dx
$$

where
$f(x) = \coth x - x \>\text{csch}^2x$.
Then, apply the Frullani's theorem to obtain
$$I= (f(0)-f(\infty))\ln\frac12=(0-1)\ln\frac12=\ln2
$$

Comment: A very smart solution.

Answer (score 4):

Merely a comment.  Find it in the literature.

*Gradshteyn, I. S.; Ryzhik, I. M.; Zwillinger, Daniel (ed.); Moll, Victor (ed.)*, [**Table of integrals, series, and products. Translated from the Russian. Translation edited and with a preface by Victor Moll and Daniel Zwillinger**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123849335), Amsterdam: Elsevier/Academic Press (ISBN 978-0-12-384933-5/hbk; 978-0-12-384934-2/ebook). xlv, 1133 p. (2015). [ZBL1300.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1300.65001).

3.529.1 is
$$
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\sinh x} - \frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{x} = -\ln 2
\tag{$*$}$$
We get the desired integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {x\cosh \left( x \right)-\sinh \left( x
 \right) }{ x\left( \sinh \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}\,{\rm d}x = \ln 2$$
when we integrate $(*)$ by parts using
$$
u = \left(\frac{1}{\sinh x} - \frac{1}{x}\right) x,
\qquad
dv = \frac{dx}{x^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks. This then links to a previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3274570/frullani-integral-int-0-infty-frac-textcschx-frac1xx-rm-dx?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\infty \left(\coth (x)-\frac{1}{x}\right) \operatorname{csch}(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(\coth(x)\operatorname{csch}(x) - \frac1{x^2} - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{x^2+\pi^2 n^2}\right) \, dx \tag1 \\
&= \left[-\operatorname{csch}(x) + \frac1x - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac x{n\pi}\right)\right]_0^\infty \\
&= -2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi} \cdot \frac\pi2 \tag2 \\
&= \ln(2) \tag3
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : recall the [partial fraction expansion of $\operatorname{csch}(x)$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Hyperbolic_Cosecant_Function)
- $(2)$ : $\dfrac1x-\operatorname{csch}(x)\to0$ as $x\to0^+$ and $x\to\infty$; the sum is uniformly convergent so we may [interchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Interchanging_limits_of_sequences_of_functions) limit with summation (see corollary 7.2)
- $(3)$ : recall the [Mercator series for $\ln(1+x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series)